# Why doesn't sinon recognize my stub?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

Let's say I have a module that exports like this:

```
module.exports = mymodule;
```

Then in my test file, I require the module and stub it.

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');

describe('Job gets sports data from API', function(){

    context('When there is a GET request', function(){
        it('will call callback after getting response', sinon.test(function(done){
            var getRequest = sinon.stub(mymodule, 'getSports');
            getRequest.yields();
            var callback = sinon.spy();
            mymodule.getSports(callback);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(callback);
            done();
        }));
    });
});
```

That works and the test passes!  But everything breaks down if I need to export more than one object.  See below:

```
module.exports = {
    api: getSports,
    other: other
};
```

Then I try to adjust my test code:

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule');

describe('Job gets sports data from API', function(){

    context('When there is a GET request', function(){
        it('will call callback after getting response', sinon.test(function(done){
            var getRequest = sinon.stub(mymodule.api, 'getSports');
            getRequest.yields();
            var callback = sinon.spy();
            mymodule.api.getSports(callback);
            sinon.assert.calledOnce(callback);
            done();
        }));
    });
});
```

In this case, my test craps out.  How can I change my stub code to work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this

```
module.exports = {
    api: getSports,
    other: other
};
```

it looks like `mymodule.api` doesn't itself have a `getSports` method. Rather, `mymodyle.api` is a reference to a `getSports` function insider your module.

Instead of stubbing `getSports` you would need to stub `api`:

```
var getRequest = sinon.stub(mymodule, 'api');
```

However, given how you're trying to stub `getSports`, you might instead want to update how you are exporting the function instead of how you are stubbing it.